Launch scripts with same nodes, how do i change one of them?
Good morning,
I am trying to control two different robots with ROS Noetic 20.04 (installed on Oracle VM), a mobile robot (MIR100) and a cobot (UR3 cb series), in order to do so i run their launch scripts:
MIR script: roslaunch mir_driver mir.launch
UR3 script: roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur3_bringup.launch robot_ip:=192.x.x.x kinematics_config:=$(rospack find ur_calibration)/ur3_robot_calibration.yaml)
As soon as i run them both an error occurs:
[WARN] Shutdown request received.
[WARN] Reason given for shutdown: [[/robot_state_publisher] Reason: new node registered with same name].
So i guess i have to change the name of the node in one of the two files, but i don't know how to properly do it, because i am afraid to make a mess. I saw that in the mir.launch file, for example, the node is defined; i don't know if i can just change the name in that file to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

The robot_state_publisher will be a mandatory node for each robot to work. One option would be to run them in their separate namespaces, but you would need to adapt the places, where it's subscribing to the publisher without the namespace. A second option is to have them publish to the same robot_state_publisher, but for that you need to combine the launch files and the whole setup!

In ROS2, we can change the name in the launch file (with 'name' tag). Probably you can do something similar in launch file in ROS1.
Example:
    Node(
        package='nav2_map_server',
        executable='map_server',
        name='map_server',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[configured_params],
        remappings=remappings
    )

